# perl autovivification of array

Tags: arrays, perl, autovivification

I am reading "impatient perl" by London. I am testing out an example from the "Reference" chapter. I am wondering why in autovivification of reference I need to put a number (any number) in [], whereas in declaring an array, I can just use [] as the empty array. Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $scal;
my $val = $scal->[2]->{somekey}->[1]->{otherkey}->[7]; 
# fails if [] instead of [7] or [1] or [99999];
# same result if [7] or [1] or [99999] is used;

$val->[3] = 19;

print Dumper $scal;
print "========\n";
print Dumper $val;
print "========\n";
print Dumper []; # this does not fail;
```

The error message was "syntax error at referenceTest.pl line 7, near "[]"
Global symbol "$val" requires explicit package name at referenceTest.pl line 15.Execution of referenceTest.pl aborted due to compilation errors."

==================
And when it works using [7], the results are:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          {
            'somekey' => [
                           undef,
                           {
                             'otherkey' => []
                           }
                         ]
          }
        ];
========
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          19
        ];
========
$VAR1 = [];
```

Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: There are two uses of `[]` here.  `$scal->[2]` does an array index lookup.  `[]` creates a reference to an anonymous array.

Answer (score 3):

`->[]` is addressing an array entry. Of course you need an index for that. Autovivification is just a side effect of addressin something that doesn't exists. If you want to assign instead, then, as Captain Obvious would readily suggest, use assignment operator `=`: `my $val = ($scal->[2]->{somekey}->[1]->{otherkey} = []);`

Answer (score 0):

a good explanation of autovivification here http://perlmaven.com/autovivification